# MimeMessageHelper Spring boot to send email

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am using spring boot to sent an email. Code snippet from my email service

```
private @Autowired JavaMailSender mailSender;
```

AND

```
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
    MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
 helper.setTo(bo.getToEmails().parallelStream().toArray(String[]::new));
helper.setBcc(bo.getBccEmails().parallelStream().toArray(String[]::new));
helper.setCc(bo.getCcEmails().parallelStream().toArray(String[]::new));
helper.setText(htmlBody, true);
helper.setText(textBody, false);
helper.setSubject(bo.getSubject());
helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(bo.getFromEmail(),bo.getSenderLabel()));
```

First I set the htmlBody and then textBody

```
    helper.setText(htmlBody, true);
helper.setText(textBody, false);
```

it override htmlBody to textBody . How can I send both text and html body using `org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;` any update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
helper.setText(htmlBody, true);
helper.setText(textBody, false);
```

Use

```
helper.setText(textBody, htmlBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `thymeleaf` as your HTML template engine.

Sample HTML code:

`MySampleHTML.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Sample Email</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:text="${sampleText}"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Sample Java Code:

```java
public class EmailSample {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine; // From Thymeleaf

    public void initiateEmailSend() {
        String processedHTMLTemplate = this.constructHTMLTemplate();

        // Start preparing the email
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = message -> {
             MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED, "UTF-8");
             helper.setFrom("Sample <sample@example.com>");
             helper.setTo("recipient@example.com");
             helper.setSubject("Sample Subject");
             helper.setText(processedHTMLTemplate, true);
        };

        mailSender.send(preparator); //send the email
    }

    // Fills up the HTML file
    private String constructHTMLTemplate() {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("sampleText", "My text sample here");
        return templateEngine.process("MySampleHTML", context);
    }
}
```

And include `thymeleaf` on your `pom.xml`

```xml
    <!-- For email HTML templating -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

NOTE: Put the `MySampleHTML.html` file on `resources/templates/` folder for `thymeleaf` to see it.